# Save grid to separate vtk and field data to separate

Tags: vtk, paraview, saving-data

I have unstructured grid and dynamic fields of data (cell data).
If I save field data to vtk format file I need to save grid in every of these files.
How can I save grid in separate file and fields in separate files and then just include (via path) link to grid? If it not possible in vtk, maybe there are some other formats that I can use for and visualize in Paraview?